# Generating an EDI 824 file from an EDI 820 file

Tags: oracle, edi, peoplesoft, peoplesoft-app-engine

I am now working on PeopleSoft and doing some tests to know how it works. 
I want to know if an EDI 824 file that says that a transaction is rejected can make the status payment change from "paid" to "awating for dispatch" or "error".

This is why I am trying to write an EDI 824 file from an EDI 820 file (that I already have).

Here's the EDI 820 file :

```
ISA*00*          *00*          *07*071000039      *11*111111118      *050411*1134*U*00401*000000002*0*P*\~
GS*RA*123456789*1234*20050411*1134*00000002*X*004010~
ST*820*000000001~
BPR*D*100.00*C*ACH*CCP*01*071000039*DA*987654123*1111111181**01*122237353*DA*0600-632181*20050103*****~
TRN*1*CM0000000077*1111111181~
CUR*PE*USD~
REF*TN*CM0000000077**~
N1*PR*US001 NEW YORK OPERATIONS**~
N1*PE*UNKNOWN**~
N1*RB*USBNK**~
SE*9*000000001~
ST*820*000000002~
BPR*D*100.00*C*ACH*CCP*01*071000039*DA*987654123*1111111181**01*122237353*DA*0600-456501*20050103*****~
TRN*1*CM0000000078*1111111181~
CUR*PE*USD~
REF*TN*CM0000000078**~
N1*PR*US001 NEW YORK OPERATIONS**~
N1*PE*UNKNOWN**~
N1*RB*TRBNK**~
SE*9*000000002~
GE*2*00000002~
IEA*1*000000002~
```

And here's what I wrote for EDI 824 file :

```
ISA*00* *00* *11*111111118*07*071000039*160428*1419*U*00401*000000002*0*P*>\
GS*AG*111111118*071000039*20050411*1134*837*X*004010\
ST*824*8370001\
BGN*00*1111111181*20050411*1134**1801100\
N1*FR*Customer\
PER*IC*If questions contact EDI Department  at 012-345-6789\
N1*TO*071000039\
PER*IC*Please correct invoice and resend by edi\
OTI*TR*TN*CM0000000077*******210\
TED*024*NO FREIGHT RECORD FOUND for LOAD\
OTI*TR*TN*CM0000000078*******210\
TED*024*NO FREIGHT RECORD FOUND FOR LOAD\
SE*11*8370001\
GE*1*837\
IEA*1*000000002\
```

The problem is that it doesn't want to import correctly into PeopleSoft, so I guess that my code is wrong somewhere. 
Does anybody see what is incorrect in my code please?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :**

My new EDI file that still can't be imported into PeopleSoft :

```
ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*111111118      *ZZ*071000039      *160429*1740*U*00401*000000002*0*P*\~
GS*AG*111111118*071000039*20050411*1134*1*X*004010~
ST*824*0001~
BGN*00*1111111181*20050411*1134**1801100~
N1*FR*Customer~
PER*IC*QUESTIONS~
N1*TO*071000039~
PER*IC*Please correct invoice and resend by edi~
OTI*TR*TN*CM0000000077~
TED*024*NO FREIGHT RECORD FOUND for LOAD~
OTI*TR*TN*CM0000000078~
TED*024*NO FREIGHT RECORD FOUND FOR LOAD~
SE*11*0001~
GE*1*1~
IEA*1*000000002~
```

PeopleSoft error message : 
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUJnu.png)

Comment: Is your ISA segment formatted correctly? Or is that just SO?  The ISA02 and 04 should be spaced out to 10 characters.  What is the actual error?  Did you try looking at your EDI file in EDI Notepad?

Comment: @Andrew : 
I changed my file a little bit (look at my edit on my question below). 
And it says that there are no errors in EDI Notepad. 
On Peoplesoft they show me an error message like the one I also added in my question post. 
My EDI file seems correct to me so I really don't understand where did I go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

the format seems valid:
https://www.stedi.com/edi/inspector?value=JIZQggVADFEAQMU6slrhAWpiBGfB%2BAHOljlAOy4wwDMAnKbgGxQAsATPXhW7AKoo%2BuFDRodoEAAoQAOgD8AUAHEQEMMryECRaFTEMIHGAFZ2%2BLbTZ4IADSFRqSkABUIRDtZq4lAIWUAciha2rhEIsZQZmwW%2BFYQeESO1FBKASIAYgBKEADCAK4AzgAuAPYAtgCmAE5KUgCiOcC5EACK-PWuwADyASBpIi7deil09HWNEM3SADaVAIaFlXAAxqXV1ZUrxXAAlgB2AG6luyvL8-sAJnCbS1dwAEYAnnCVl7tK3S7AEC45LkFcgBZMRiCgUJQueoAEWgnggAW6cGy9WAygAEi44Fl6rlullocjuvwAoSAGbrOAAGW6YGhn2%2Bv3%2BgJBoJgFCIkJhcOsiOROLRmOxuPxhIyxNJRKy1Np9MUIHqWlEPhUipEKuA9UgIjZMA4SiAA&view=rich&sftp=&account=8c20106a-2ed4-4df6-9777-6e3370f6dc19

tested here.

Comment: Please don't use links as an answer, especially not this one. Take the revelant information and even try to expand a little bit on the topic.